# How to run a chrome extension from a click button?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, metamask

After a lot of times spend to find the solution, i'm here to ask your help.

I have a simple chrome extension, and what I try to do is simple:
Detect on the page when a button is clicked, then, open the extension `popup.html`.

A good example is MetaMask, the html page can open the popup to connect the wallet, send transaction ...

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

1. Run a content script on the page and send a message to the background when the button is clicked.

> ```
> // Content Script
>
> button.addEventListener("click", () => {
>   chrome.runtime.sendMessage("OpenPopup")
> })
> ```

2. Catch the message in the background and create a window with your popup URL. Provide a "top" and a "left" value to place it at the top right of the users' screen. Use the type "popup" to get rid of the stuff that is usually at the top of a window. Read more about the chrome.windows.create method [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#method-create).

> ```
> // Background Script
>
> chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(request => {
>
>   if (request == "OpenPopup") {
>
>       chrome.windows.create({
>           url: "popup.html",
>           type: "popup",
>           focused: true,
>           width: 400,
>           height: 600,
>           top: 0,
>           left: screen.width - 400,
>       }, () => {
>           console.log("Opened popup!")
>       })
>
>   }
>
> })
> ```